# Replace text except number using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace some text using jQuery leaving the number.

Replacing text in jQuery is easy but I don't know a lot about regex to leave the number part alone.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="example">10 Examples</div>
```

What I'd like to do is change `10 Examples` to something else but leaving the number part in.

Comment: Does it always look like that, a number, then a space, then the text to replace ?

Comment: It'll always be number + space + text. I'd like to replace the text part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parseInt` for a non regex solution.

```
$(".example").text(function(i, txt) {

     return parseInt(txt, 10) + " your new message";
});
```

Comment: Not a problem, I always avoid using a regex if possible, good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0):

Split on space, keep the first value, being the number, and add new text, start with a space as that would be removed when splitting :

```
$('.example').text(function(i,txt) {
    return txt.split(/\s+/).shift() + ' your new text goes here';
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4QJzm/2/)

Comment: @undefined - someone probably did'nt get it, as usual, and downvoted ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div class="example">10 <b>Examples</b></div>

$('.example b').text('sample text');
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to the HTML so I can't add in another tag otherwise I would :/

Answer (score -1):

Using [A-Za-z] as a regex expression will find anything A-Z and a-z ingoring all numbers and special characters